# Access Control / Word Press -- Not able to edit, delete

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I am setting up our CRM and somehow do not have permission to run reports, duplicate users, edit, delete.

I am familiar with the Word Press permissions page -- still can't access the membership/contact files I uploaded from mail chimp last nite, not able to duplicate search, not able to run reports.

Thanks for your help!